# Create a patch build to repair an existing installation of electron-react desktop application for MAC OS

Tags: electron, patch, electron-builder, dmg

Currently, I use electron-builder to create an installer/distributable for an electron-react desktop application. I have the necessary configurations in package.json. I use 'yarn build' and 'yarn dist' commands to invoke the build process. https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder has all of the steps. The installer is quite heavy(500MB) with all the libraries and source code. So every time a feature is added it becomes quite a hectic task to rebuild and share it for production. The actual need of this post is that I'm looking for ways to create a patch build that I hope will be relatively light and that can be applied over the original installation as a bug fix/repair. I made quite some google searches and didn't get any clue on that. I'm hoping that there must be any node module that creates a patch build by doing a comparison of the previously created 'dist' and the latest source code. There could also be a totally independent software that can take up two installers and return a patch installer from the comparison. Any answer or redirection would be of great help.